# How to effectively share parameters between two Pytorch models

Tags: pytorch, parameters, shared

I want to enforce symmetry in my model like `f(x,y) = f(y,x)` and would like to achieve it by defining two models `model1(x,y)` and `model2(y,x)` but let them have same architecture and parameters. I could share their parameters by

```py
for name, param1 in model1.named_parameters():
    if name in model2.state_dict() and param1.shape == model2.state_dict()[name].shape:
      model2.state_dict()[name].data = param1.data
```

Does it make sense to share parameters this way? Do I have to define two optimizers for each model? Does

```py
optimizer = optim.Adam(list(model1.parameters()) + list(model2.parameters()))  # Combine parameters
```

make sense since the models share parameters, assuming one of my losses is

```py
criterion(model1(x,y), model2(y,x))
```

I would appreciate a minimal working example supposing my models have dynamic layer configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is not clear in your question is whether you want symmetry on one model ("enforce symmetry in my **model**") or between two (implied when you introduce `model1` and `model2`).

If you want to enforce symmetry on a single model, you can minimize some distance between `model(x,y)` and `model(y,x)`? In that case you only require one model, and one optimizer and
enforce that property on `model`, and not on two distinct models.

Besides, I don't clearly see what you would get by having `model1` and `model2` distinct: `model1` would `model2` be "symmetric"... `model2` defined as `x,y: model1(y,x)` would suffice too no? Maybe there is more to it and you indeed want two models?

Comment: Indeed I just want to model a function that obeys `f(x,y)=f(y,x)`, so it's one model. I assume that making two forward passes, one for `f(x,y)` and the other for `f(y,x)`  before backpropagation might be problematic (I might be wrong, and I guess that should have been my question). That's why I thought of going the route of using two models that are essentially the same in parameters to achieve it. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, it isn't problematic, you can perform two forward passes, compute your loss, and backpropagate, it should work.